# Doctrine - OneToOne relation - EntityNotFoundException

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I want to specify relation between two entities Item and ItemPrice. Item can have a price, but does not have to, so it should be something like left join in sql. I used OneToOne relation, JoinColumn with nullable=true and I am getting **EntityNotFoundException** exception. Here is my code:

```
class Item
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $item_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $image_file;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ItemPrice")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="item_id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $price;
...
}


class ItemPrice
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $item_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $gold;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $silver;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $bronze;
...
}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
`item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`image_file` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uk_item_name` (`name`));

CREATE TABLE `item_price` (
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`gold` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`silver` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`bronze` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`));
```

I think what I did is called unidirectional OneToOne:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional
Which in my opinion is exactly what I need.

Comment: can you provide your namespace definitions?

Comment: Any success solving your issue with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think your mapping is wrong.

you write `nullable=true` for your `item_id` join column in your `OneToOne` association with `ItemPrice`. meaning if `item_id` is `null` there is no associating ItemPrice. But `item_id` is the primary id column and thus will always have a value, so the ORM will always try to find an `ItemPrice` for your `Item` resulting in a **EntityNotFoundException**
You should either make `ItemPrice` the owning side of the relationship or you should make a `price_id` in your `ItemPrice` and use this as a join column.

You should consider using Doctrine for creating/inserting your tables and validating your entity definitions, then you won't have these kind of issues.